# HTML tags for choicefield in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I cant seem to find ANYWHERE on how to do choicefield HTML tags in Django. I found radio buttons and other advance  choice fields, but nothing on basic drop down HTML tags with Django. I have `models.py` and `view.py` set up passing `list1` to the `html` pages, but cant seem to make it display anything except

```
<select style="width:300px">
  {% for choice in list1.VIEWS %}
  <option>{{choice}}</option>
  {{choice}}
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated

#### models.py

```
class preset_list(models.Model):
    VIEWS = (
        ('1', 'X'),
        ('2', 'Y'),
    )
    query_choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=VIEWS)
```

#### view.py

```
list1 = models.preset_list()
return render_to_response('services.html', 
         {'array':json.dumps(data, cls=SpecialEncoder),
         'list1':list1},
                          )
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  You say you "cant seem to make it display anything except" but then you show some template code.  Surely that's not django output?  Are you using a form?  Please show model, view, form (if applicable) and template and then show what django is producing (probably straight html) and then show what you want it to produce.  Then someone can help.

Comment: I updated with python code, I am looking for simple dropdown menu, to select and get back some data.

Comment: When you said you "can't find anywhere", did you think to look at the [forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield)?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes, it had no HTML code for it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ModelForms are your friend here.

#### models.py

```
class PresetList(models.Model):
    VIEWS = (
        ('1', 'X'),
        ('2', 'Y'),
    )
    query_choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=VIEWS)
```

#### forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from . import models

class PresetListForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.PresetList
```

#### view.py

```
from . import forms

def my_view(request):

    preset_form = forms.PresetListForm()

    return render_to_response('services.html', {
        'array': json.dumps(data, cls=SpecialEncoder),
        'preset_form': preset_form,
    })
```

#### services.html

```
<form method=POST action="/somewhere">
    {{ preset_form.as_p }}
</form>
```

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield

Comment: can you try it with just `{{ preset_form }}` ?

Comment: generally if you get nothing out in the template, you're either not putting data into the context, or are not using the same name in the template. Can you double-check that the right values are going into context? Otherwise, [dpaste](https://dpaste.de/) your current code, and i'll try to debug.

Comment: I can verify all named properly, I traced back the name through all the files where it is involved from `forms.py` to `html` and nothing. I can invoke `preset_form`, by doing what I posted in the original question, through `.VIEWS`
Here is the link https://dpaste.de/D1DX
Thanks a lot!

Comment: A couple of problems with your dpaste:  1)  the {% csrf_token %} is not in the <form>...</form> tags.  2)  csrf_token is only output if the user is authenticated.  3)  your header "HTML" - did you mean to say "template"?  I'm assuming this is the template named in your view.  4)  the template is lacking the "{% extends %}" stuff.  Also, when you say "nothing appears", please have a look in the developer view of the browser and show us what does appear.  Is there a <html></html>, at least?

Comment: @BrendaJ.Butler I added `csrf token` inside the form, and user is logged in. `extends` stuff? I load `static` and etc at the top of the file, what else am I missing?

Comment: When I check preset_form for any options in the `view.py` before it gets sent out to HTML, it has only 1 option `meta`, no other options such as `as_p` and etc

Comment: @rodling You mean `[attr for attr in dir(preset_form) if not attr.startswith('__')] == ['meta']` before you return from the view?

Comment: @ChrisWesseling say again? i have no idea what you meant by that

Comment: I don't see how saying it again conveys more meaning. ;-) It's how I'd translate your 'check preset_form for options...' into Python code. *Checking for options* seems a bit overloaded with different meanings, especially in the context of SelectBoxes... Just trying to poke through the ambiguity of natural language and mismatching meaning of terms.

Comment: @rodling can you put `print dir(preset_form)` above render_to_response, and tell us what it gives you?

Comment: @Thomas it lists a lot of items, `Meta` is first on the list. But `as_p`, `as_ul` and many other items are on it. When I try to play around with `preset_form` in Spyder it only gives me `meta` option

Answer (score 2):

Give the generic [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) a try.

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .models import PresetList

class PresetListCreate(CreateView):
    model = PresetList
```

presetlist_form.html

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

we can use this without using django form

```
<select style="width:300px" name="presen">
  {% for val, name in preset_list.VIEWS %}
  <option value="{{val}}">{{name}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want done, but if you eant to send 1 when X is displayed, the following should work:

```
<select style="width:300px">
  {% for choice in list1.VIEWS %}
  <option value={{choice.0}}>{{choice.1}}</option>
  {{choice}}
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: creates the dropdown, however it does not populate it

Answer (score 1):

You can create a form with a drop-down and tell it which values to populate it with like so:

**Form**

```
class MyDropDownForm(forms.ModelForm):
    somerow = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        # change this queryset if you want to limit the options
        queryset= MyModel.objects.all().values('somerow'),
        widget=Select(),
        required=True,
    )        

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['somerow']
```

**View**

```
class MyView(DjangoTemplateView):

    def get(self, request):
        # you can set an instance when creating the form to set the value
        # to be that of an existing row in your model
        # MyDropDownForm(instance=MyModel.objects.filter(id=1))
        form = MyDropDownForm()
        return render_to_response('app/page.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        # if you had set the instance in the get you want to do that again
        form = MyDropDownForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return render_to_response('app/success.html')
        return render_to_response('app/page.html', {'form': form})
```

**Page.html**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.id  }}
    {{ form.myrow }}
    {% if form.myrow.errors %}
        {% for error in form.myrow.errors %}<p>{{ error }}</p>{% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

[Take a look at the docs here for more info on creating model forms.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)