# Passing variables in twitter-bootstrap without page reloading

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to django, and i am sure there is a better way to pass variables. I have a drop down object from `twitter bootstrap` and I wish to pass the values back to Python so it can query different data and display it on the page. Basically, I am looking for dynamic charts
This is my attempt, but it causes the page to be reloaded, which is not something I want

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Graphs <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a role="menuitem"  href="{% url 'ins_graph' 0 %}">graph 1</a></li>
    <li><a role="menuitem" href="{% url 'ins_graph' 1 %}">graph 2</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'ins_graph' 3 %}">graph 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I use Google Chart API to display the data. I also had a problem with drop down menus in plain vanilla django, that question may help clarify, since it has more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875455/html-tags-for-choicefield-in-django).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you look for Ajax calls. To change Content on your page without reloading it, You Need to Code javascript.

More Info about it: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ 
jQuery is a bootstrap dependency.

Cheers

Comment: no experience in it, any sample code suggestions how to do so to kickstart my soulsearching with this?